# Get user's groups where user is member

Tags: facebook, sdk

How get user's groups where user is member?

Facebook php sdk v2.9

There is a method that returns the user's groups: /me/groups, but this method return only groups created by user.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get all groups anymore, you can only get user managed groups with the `user_managed_groups` permission. The permission to get all groups (`user_groups`) is deprecated/gone.